# Execute code monthly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this backup code that I want to execute monthly, I am familiar with using the job or maintenance plan in sql server management studio but I would like to code it instead of using the sql server job or maintenance plan.

.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Button111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());

    string backupDIR = "C:\backup";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(backupDIR))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDIR);
    }
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database iporma to disk= '" + backupDIR + "\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_HHss") + ".Bak'", con);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblError.Text = "Completed";


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error" + ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

please go easy on me I'm still new to this.

Comment: Take a look into hangfire: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: IMHO that's a terrible idea. It's like saying you want to serve up web pages using SQL Agent

Comment: Thanks I will take a look into that, Thank you for your opinion I respect that it is just that I want to try it out for my fulfillment

Comment: Use Windows scheduled tasks to launch your backup code on schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Create windows service or windows scheduled task to execute this code.You will find good articles on Google explaining how to create windows services.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is correct little change in query: you take month then you should use  only MMM or mMm:

```
 sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database iporma to disk= '" + backupDIR + "\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM") + ".Bak'", con);
```

Comment: Thanks I will change that, but do you have any Idea on how I can execute the backup code every month?

Comment: use  this string month=system.datetime.now.tostring(MMM); and use this month on if condtion you can use it up every month :)  if(month!=""){ } use this on top

Comment: @karthicbe Whaatt?

Comment: wait i will upload it as answer

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
protected void Button111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());
string month=System.DateTime.Now.toString("dd-MMM");// every month it has to be changed..
string backupDIR = "C:\backup";
if(month!="")
{
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(backupDIR))
   {
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDIR);
}
try
{
    con.Open();
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database iporma to disk= '" + backupDIR + "\" + "Month.ToString()" + ".Bak'", con);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    lblError.Text = "Completed";


}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = "Error" + ex.ToString();
}
 }
}
```

Comment: But if you perform the backup on the first day of the month and the last day of the month, will the first backup not get overwritten? Moreover, does OP not want it to be more of a scheduled thing?

Comment: sure try this...

Comment: And the more important point? That OP presumably wants it to be a scheduled thing?

Comment: the date and month of the current year will be posted on string  month and you have save same file it has to be overwritten.. try this if you got any thing tell me :)

Comment: Sigh. Your'e ignoring my question.

Comment: i answered  try this .. if you got any query  tel me

Comment: As I've asked twice now: how do you schedule this?

Comment: Am I to understand that you don't know how to run this on a schedule?